# Removing attribute from map in dynamodb

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have the following dynamodb table and want to remove "oldInfo" from the attribute "accounts" using update_expression = f"REMOVE accounts.oldInfo" however that does not work. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions for this? Note that the "accounts" attribute is a map and so is "oldInfo".

```
{
 "accounts": {
   "oldInfo": {
    "oldStuff": []
   }
   "otherInfo": {
    "otherStuff": []
   }
 }
}
```

This is the code that I am using to remove "oldInfo"

```
self.clean_up_dynamo_db.updateitem(table_name=self.table_name,
                                   key={
                                       "partitionKey": item["partitionKey"],
                                       "sortKey": item["sortKey"]
                                   },
                                   update_expression=f"REMOVE {self.attribute}")
```

Comment: The full operation is that update_expression = f"REMOVE accounts.oldInfo" and there are no errors that I am receiving. The only issue I am having is that oldInfo is not being removed from the dynamo table. Is it possible that accounts.oldInfo is not the correct format for the remove expression?

Comment: That's just the update_expression portion of the operation.  A full operation looks like this:


var params = {
    TableName: "table_name",
    Key: {
        "key": "value"
    },
    UpdateExpression: "REMOVE accounts.oldInfo",
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
}

Comment: This was done in python and was made as a script to remove that attribute from multiple items in the table.

self.clean_up_dynamo_db.updateitem(table_name=self.table_name, key = {"partitionKey": item["partitionKey"], "sortKey": item["sortKey"] }, update_expression = f"REMOVE {self.attribute}")

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question to include this code snippet.  Many people won't read this far into the comment to understand your problem.  Also, what's with the letter `f` just before the `REMOVE` ?

Comment: the letter f is used to format strings and I used it because I am including self.attribute

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a clear example in the DDB docs, so I replicated your situation in my AWS account.

I created a map attribute named `accounts` and gave it keys of `oldInfo` and `otherInfo`.  I executed the following operation, which removed `accounts.oldInfo` as expected.

```
 const params = {
    TableName: "YOUR_TABLE_NAME",
    Key: {
      PK: "PARTITION_KEY",
      SK: "SORT_KEY"
    },
    UpdateExpression: "REMOVE accounts.otherInfo"
  }

  await ddbClient.updateItem(params);
```

Although this snippet is in JavaScript, it confirms that you are going about the operation correctly according to the DDB API.

Perhaps there is something else going on in your code that is preventing the operation from succeeding?  Are you certain the variables you are sending `update_item` are as you expect them?

Comment: Thanks for replicating on your end and I am certain the variables that I am sending in update_item are as I expect them. If I do accounts instead of accounts.oldInfo then it works fine by removing accounts and everything that it holds such as oldInfo and otherInfo.